# Excel VBA application caller copy 2 ranges

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

Friends, I'm very poor in programming but maybe someone is willing to help.

My spreadsheet contains 18 ranges and 2 different headers in protected area. I need to copy and combine 1 header and 1 range to another, unprotected area. User should press a button and macro brings data to new position where it can be pasted.

For button operation I have an application.caller for hiding and showing rows. I think this is a good start. I also have a copy macro for 1 set of ranges. I'd like to combine these 2 in to a new macro.

```
Sub Macro_copy_RIVA1()

    Range("RHEAD").Copy
    Range("RIVA1").Copy
    Application.Goto Reference:="R1120C2"
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
End Sub
```

My application caller for hide/show rows is (thanks to Stackoverflow)

```
Sub ShowHideRows()

    Dim arr

    'split the calling button name into an array
    '  (array will be zero-based)
    arr = Split(Application.Caller, "_")

    '**EDIT** check array is expected size...
    If UBound(arr) <> 3 Then Exit Sub

    If IsNumeric(arr(1)) And IsNumeric(arr(2)) Then
        With ActiveSheet  ' "Me" if the code is in the sheet module, else "ActiveSheet"
            .Unprotect Password:=""

            'arr(1) determines start row
            'arr(2) determines # of rows
            'arr(3) determines if rows are hidden or not
            .Cells(arr(1), 1).Resize(arr(2), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = (arr(3) = "H")
            .Protect Password:=""
        End With
    End If
End Sub`
```

My ranges are called :

Header:

- RHEAD1
- RHEAD2

Ranges:

- RIVA1
- RIVA2
- RIVA3
- .....
- RIVA6
- RMVA1
- RMVA2
- .....
- RMVA12

Proposed name of button : btn_RHEAD1_RIVA1 or btn_RHEAD2_RMVA12

How can I run a macro from an application caller that performs the copying task ?
Thanks